# Save file to public directory in iOS using cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a cordova application that downloads pdf file from internet and save it to local filesystem using cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-file-transfer. In next step I would like to open the file using default application for specified mimetype. I am using cordova-plugin-file-opener2 plugin for that. Directory where the file is saved needs to be readable for chosen 3rd party application to open the file. On android there are several publicly accessible filesystem directories and I have it working correctly. But I am unable to find the right directory where I need to save the file in case of iOS, to make it available for chosen default 3rd party app.

cordova-plugin-file says in its docs that all directories available in RW mode to cordova application are private: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#file-system-layouts

But how does it come? Concept of opening file by default 3rd party application based on mimetype is standard in every OS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559455/how-to-make-files-dynamically-generated-saved-by-cordova-ios-app-accessible-to-t

Answer (score 1):

iOS hasn't publicly accessible filesystem directories.
One way - use sharing via UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Thank you for response. Priority for me is to find existing cordova solution. Writing my own plugin or bridge using UIActivityViewController to make it work is really the last possible way for me.

Comment: I only want to help, that no publicly folder in iOS.

Comment: Igor, do you know how to then expose some files in IOS for the end user?

Answer (score 0):

I am using cordova-plugin-file-opener2 plugin with IOS. I save my file in cordova.file.cacheDirectory and this works fine for me when I save a zip file into that location. I first had to install a zip file manager so to handle the mimeType = application/zip. The zip file manager I used was a free version of "Zip Viewer" which seems ok but has a few ads.

To get it to work on Android I had to save my file in
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory it failed silently when I used cordova.file.cacheDirectory for Android. You can't use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory for IOS because it is not defined for IOS according to the Cordova File Plugin docs.

Here is a code snippet that is called when the file is saved:

```
var fileName = "myfile.zip";
//for IOS
var filePath = cordova.file.cacheDirectory+"/Download/"+fileName;
//for Android
//var filePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"/Download/"+fileName;

var mimeType = "application/zip";
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    filePath,
    mimeType,
    {error : function(){
                   my.alert("ERROR opening with cordova.plugins.fileOpener2");
             },
     success : function(){
                   my.log("SUCCESS opening zip file");
               }
     });
```