# How to make files dynamically generated/saved by Cordova iOS APP accessible to the end user?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios, cordova-plugin-file

I'm using the `cordova-plugin-file` to save some data image to the user's iOS phone.

```
saveBlobAsImageFile(folderpath, filename, blob) {
  const onError = function(msg) {
    // handles error
  }

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(folderpath, function(dir) {
    console.log("Access to the directory granted");
    dir.getFile(filename, { create: true }, function(file) {
      console.log("File created")
      file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.write(blob);
        console.log("Written file")
      }, onError)
    }, onError)
  }, onError)
}
```

for the `folderpath`, I tried all of these 5 options:

```
let folderpath = cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory;
let folderpath1 = cordova.file.documentsDirectory; 
let folderpath2 = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
let folderpath3 = cordova.file.cacheDirectory;
let folderpath4 = cordova.file.tempDirectory;
```

After running the function `saveBlobAsImageFile`, the log shows the successful writing, but when I go to Files or Library in my simulator/iPhone, I cannot found any saved file.

Update: When I run in simulator, after clicking save, I found the file saved in these folders:

```
file:///Users/ngoctuan001/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2964FE69-A5FE-4516-B8F1-C45488DBE2B5/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EF9FF0C-903E-481F-87A0-9A1CEDA4DE5D/Library/Cloud/
file:///Users/ngoctuan001/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2964FE69-A5FE-4516-B8F1-C45488DBE2B5/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EF9FF0C-903E-481F-87A0-9A1CEDA4DE5D/Documents/
file:///Users/ngoctuan001/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2964FE69-A5FE-4516-B8F1-C45488DBE2B5/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EF9FF0C-903E-481F-87A0-9A1CEDA4DE5D/Library/NoCloud/
file:///Users/ngoctuan001/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2964FE69-A5FE-4516-B8F1-C45488DBE2B5/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EF9FF0C-903E-481F-87A0-9A1CEDA4DE5D/Library/Caches/
```

However, when I go to the simulator files and library, these images are not found.

**How to make dynamically generated files by the iOS Cordova APP accessible to the end user through the library?**

Comment: Jake, did you happen to find any other solution?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira hi , it's been a long time so im not really sure now, based on my answer below, it seems that i switched to different plugin. Maybe you can try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `UIFileSharingEnabled`, `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`, `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` all as YES on plist file, your app files will be visible to iOS Explorer. The main source is [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85942).

Thus you can edit your `config.xml` adding these entries inside `<platform name="ios">`

```xml
<edit-config target="UIFileSharingEnabled" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
  <true/>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
  <true/>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="UISupportsDocumentBrowser" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
  <true/>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Note I had to platform remove/add ios for the options to show-up in Xcode (app-name > Resources > app-name-Info.plist).  Also, the options Value defaulted to 'NO' in Xcode, so I had to manually change them to 'YES'.  (Xcode=12.4, Cordova=10.0.0, cordova-ios=6.2.0.)

Comment: Changing `<true/>` to `<string>YES</string>` in each entry fixed it for me.

Comment: Oops, seems you were right in the first place.  apple rejected my app with ERROR ITMS-90039: "Type Mismatch. The value for the Info.plist key UIFileSharingEnabled is not of the required type for that key"  I changed it back to <true/> and it is accepted.

Comment: @phatpaul can you share your resolution? With use of "<true/>" plist values are set to false

Comment: @phatpaul do you confirm that now is ok?

Comment: @worm69 Yeah, that is what I experienced at first.  I'm not sure how I fixed it, but I can only confirm that it is working now.  The Xcode plist editor shows "YES", and if I open the .plist in Xcode (app-name > Resources > app-name-Info.plist) by right-click and choose to Open As -> Source Code, it shows the values as <true/>.  I did try platform remove/add and it came back working as well...

Answer (score 1):

I instead changing to `cordova-plugin-x-social-sharing` to save to photos. It seems that its not easy to touch the file system of iOS like android. If it helps.